# smbclient NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE

Tags: smbclient

Trying to access and smb drive on a Windows machine (Windows 10 Pro) in linux (CentOS7) via `smbclient`, but having login problems. Seeing...

```bsh
[root@airflowetl etl]# smbclient -U my_user -L 172.18.7.102
Enter SAMBA\my_user's password: 
session setup failed: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
```

... even though I can successfully log into this remote machine when using the same username and password I use in the command above.

I don't know very much about smb, but my `smb.conf` file looks like ...

```bsh
[root@airflowetl etl]# cat /etc/samba/smb.conf
# See smb.conf.example for a more detailed config file or
# read the smb.conf manpage.
# Run 'testparm' to verify the config is correct after
# you modified it.

[global]
    workgroup = SAMBA
    security = user

    passdb backend = tdbsam

    printing = cups
    printcap name = cups
    load printers = yes
    cups options = raw

[homes]
    comment = Home Directories
    valid users = %S, %D%w%S
    browseable = No
    read only = No
    inherit acls = Yes

[printers]
    comment = All Printers
    path = /var/tmp
    printable = Yes
    create mask = 0600
    browseable = No

[print$]
    comment = Printer Drivers
    path = /var/lib/samba/drivers
    write list = @printadmin root
    force group = @printadmin
    create mask = 0664
    directory mask = 0775

[users]
    path = /samba/users
    browseable = yes
    read only = yes
    force create mode = 0660
    force directory mode = 2770
    admin users = @"DOMAIN+domain admins"
```

(I did not set it up, so may not be able to answer questions about why it is configured this way). Based on this and an answer that I saw on another forum (https://askubuntu.com/a/109510/760862) I tried including the domain and workgroup in the command...

```bsh
[root@airflowetl etl]# smbclient -U USER/my_user -L 172.18.7.102 -W SAMBA
Enter SAMBA\my_user's password: 
session setup failed: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
```

... which still didn't work.

I can log into a shared smb drive that is hosted on the machine like...

```bsh
[root@airflowetl etl]# smbclient -U my_user \\\\H021BSBD20\shared_folder
Enter SAMBA\my_user 's password:
```

where H021BSBD20 is the Device Name I see in the System Settings on the remote machine, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Anyone with more experience have any ideas what could be going on here? Any more debugging steps I could try? Am I just totally misunderstanding something here?

Comment: I think was due to the fact that that my_user was given access the specific share location `\\\\devicename\\shared_folder`, but not the machine itself, so just trying to connect to the IP would not work since have no login for that user. Need to check with admin who set it up if this interpretation is correct. Will update.